# How to get [url] from array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array which returns the information below. I'm trying to get the [Url] link from that and use it for my image, how can i do that? sorry i'm quite new to all this.

```
The converted array is:
object(stdClass)#4653 (9) { [“sizes”]=> object(stdClass)#4658 (3) { [“thumbnail”]=> object(stdClass)#4617 (4) { [“height”]=> int(150) [“width”]=> int(150) [“url”]=> string(60) “https://magdek.loc/app/uploads/2022/03/slide-1-2-150×150.jpg” [“orientation”]=> string(9) “landscape” } [“medium”]=> object(stdClass)#4659 (4) { [“height”]=> int(300) [“width”]=> int(300) [“url”]=> string(60) “https://magdek.loc/app/uploads/2022/03/slide-1-2-300×300.jpg” [“orientation”]=> string(9) “landscape” } [“full”]=> object(stdClass)#4629 (4) { [“url”]=> string(52) “https://magdek.loc/app/uploads/2022/03/slide-1-2.jpg” [“height”]=> int(311) [“width”]=> int(311) [“orientation”]=> string(9) “landscape” } } [“mime”]=> string(10) “image/jpeg” [“type”]=> string(5) “image” [“subtype”]=> string(4) “jpeg” [“id”]=> int(155) [“url”]=> string(52) “https://magdek.loc/app/uploads/2022/03/slide-1-2.jpg” [“alt”]=> string(0) “” [“link”]=> string(52) “https://magdek.loc/product/hot-air-dryers/slide-1-3/” [“caption”]=> string(0) “”
```

I'm using a foreach loop and the $item returns the code above but i'm not sure how to get the image from it just.

This is the code i have so far for this:

```
<?php
        $my_array = json_decode($args['images']);
      ?>
      <picture-gallery>
        <?php if(($my_array)):
        foreach($my_array as $item): ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <?php var_dump($item);?>
        </div>
        <?php
          endforeach;
          endif;
        ?>
      </picture-gallery>
```

Comment: Share the code, you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, I updated the code to what I have in my file.

Comment: What is output of `var_dump($item);`

Comment: It's the converted array at the very top

Comment: echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_array);
echo "</pre>";

Let me know output for the same. you will get idea what exactly issue is.

Answer (score 0):

`$item` is object which have `"sizes"` object with three more objects of different sizes `“thumbnail”`, `“medium”` and `“full”`

You can do get your required size by change inside following code

```
<?php echo $item->sizes->full->url; ?>
```

Comment or delete `<?php var_dump($item);?>` inside `loop` and Put above line there.

**Note**: You need to replace `->full->` with your required size

Comment: I am glad that my answer helps you. Please accept my answer if you found it helpful. It motivates me to help others